# HDMI audio not detected after update for AMD Graphics

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi

---

Edit: added OS information below

---

My HDMI audio output from AMD RX6600 has disappeared after update and shutdown yesterday night, I've performed the follow checks:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Does not solve the issue

```
aplay -l
```

Output:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

```
lspci
```

...
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT]
...

```
pavucontrol
```

only Generic audio showed up

```
pactl list short sinks
```

2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Does not work

Does anyone has any idea on how to get around this problem? Thanks so much!

Spes:
Dell Precision 5810
X99 - E5 1620 V3  Haswell
AMD RX6600

Edit:
Linux 5.19.0-35-generic, Release 22.04.2 LTS,

Comment: Opps sorry, Linux 5.19.0-35-generic, Release 22.04.2 LTS, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: If you select an older 5.15 kernel at grub during boot; is it still working?  (ie. when using the GA kernel.. at last resort that maybe a work around if a solution isn't found with the HWE kernel stack (ie. 5.19 etc))

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about this! It works now, so we can narrow down as a driver issue, I'll report it through Ubuntu, Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Can you share the link to the bug report?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: here, the bugreport No HDMI audio under 5.19.0-35 (regression from -32) : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2009136

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue with 5.15.0-35 kernel, the problem went away with 5.15.0-67 kernel

Comment: 5.19.0-35 kernel broke this again